# To whom does the Chatur Vyuha Avatars of Lord Vishnu exactly meditates upon according to scriptures.?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, vishnu, pancharatra, vyuha

According to Mahabharata, other scriptures and Vaishnava agamas, Lord Vishnu has his [Chatur Vyuha](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caturvy%C5%ABha) Avatars they are Vasudeva, Samkarsana, Pradyumna, Aniruddha. [Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c039.htm) ( Shanti Parva) says that, from Vasudeva came Samkarsana then from Samkarsana came Pradyumna and then from Pradyumna came Aniruddha. Almost like Lord Krishna's famuly tree except Lord Krishna and Lord BalaRama (as they were brothers and Lord BalaRama was the eldest one).

As for my question, I know that they ultimately meditates upon Lord Narayana (aka Para Vasudeva) only. But my real question is.:

According to scriptures does they also meditates upon their higher selfs like Aniruddha meditating upon Pradyumna or Samkarsana or Vasudeva or all 3 of them and so on for the other 3 also.???

Comment: Just seeking a clarification - where did you read that the four vyuhas ultimately meditate on the Para Vâsudeva?

Comment: @Vivikta well, its kind of a common sense right. In Vaishnavism, Para Vasudeva is the name of Brahman. And everyone meditates on Brahman only.

Comment: I hope this clarifies your queries. ..

Comment: Well, yeah maybe, I'm not sure ; Also, as far as I recall, there's no such mention in the Pancharatras - the most authoritative texts in most Vaishnava sects. Because all those vyuhas are Vishnu themselves, with different degrees of opulences (generally two vibuhutis assigned to each). But yeah, after the Dissolution each vyuha comes into form one by one and remain so for several divine years, until the "lower vyuha" manifests from the "higher", maybe in that there's some meditation going on.

Comment: In Vedas, also Its said that the truth or Bhagawan is only one and wise calls him by different names. But still meditation is a part of our sashtras and culture. Even meditation on self also. As self (arman) is considered as Brahman. So yeah, i think every Sanatani deity does meditation of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Śhiva Purana. Section 7.2 - Vāyavīya-saṃhitā (2). Chapter 31 - The Hymn of lord Śiva says that they pray on both Shiva and Shakti.

> atha viṣṇurmaheśasya śivasyaiva parā tanuḥ |
> vāritattvādhipaḥ sākṣādavyaktapadasaṃsthitaḥ || 126 ||
> nirguṇassattvabahulastathaiva guṇakevalaḥ |
> avikārābhimānī ca trisādhāraṇavikriyaḥ || 127 ||
> asādhāraṇakarmā ca sṛṣṭyādikaraṇātpṛthak |
> dakṣiṇāṃgabhavenāpi spardhamānaḥ svayaṃbhuvā || 128 ||
> ādyena brahmaṇā sākṣātsṛṣṭaḥ sraṣṭā ca tasya tu |
> aṃḍasyāṃtarbahirvartī viṣṇurlokadvayādhipaḥ || 129 ||
> asurāṃtakaraścakrī śakrasyāpi tathānujaḥ |
> prādurbhūtaśca daśadhā bhṛguśāpacchalādiha || 130 ||
> bhūbhāranigrahārthāya svecchayāvātarakṣitau |
> aprameyabalo māyī māyayā mohayañjagat || 131 ||
> mūrtiṃ kṛtvā mahāviṣṇuṃ sadāśiṣṇumathāpi vā |
> vaiṣṇavaiḥ pūjito nityaṃ mūrtitrayamayāsane || 132 ||
> śivapriyaḥ śivāsaktaḥ śivapādārcane rataḥ |
> śivasyājñāṃ puraskṛtya sa me diśatu maṃgalam || 133 ||

126-133. **Viṣṇu is another form of the great lord Śiva himself.** He is the lord of the principle of water. He is stationed in the region of the unmanifest. He is Nirguṇa. He is predominantly Sāttvic as well as possessed of single Guṇa. He does not identify himself with the created things. He has the three general aberrations. He is of extraordinary activity apart form that of creation. He compares with Brahmā though he is born of the right part of Śiva. He is created by the first Brahmā and he is his creator too. Viṣṇu abides within and without the universe. He is the lord of the worlds. With his discus he destroys Asuras. He is the younger brother of Indra. He has manifested himself in ten forms under the curse of Bhṛgu. He incarnated on the earth at his will for removing the burden of the Earth. His strength is immeasurable and incomprehensible. He is the wielder of Māyā. He fascinates the universe with his Māyā in the form of Mahāviṣṇu and Sadāviṣṇu. He is worshipped by the devotees of Viṣṇu in the seat of the three Mūrtis. He is a favourite of Śiva and is fondly attached to him. **He is engaged in the worship of his feet.** May he grant me what is auspicious at the behest of Śiva.

> vāsudevo 'niruddhaśca pradyumnaśca tataḥ paraḥ |
> saṃkarṣaṇassamākhyātāścatasro mūrtayo hareḥ || 134 ||
> matsyaḥ kūrmo varāhaśca nārasiṃho 'tha vāmanaḥ |
> rāmatrayaṃ tathā kṛṣṇo viṣṇusturagavaktrakaḥ || 135 ||
> cakraṃ nārāyaṇasyāstraṃ pāṃcajanyaṃ ca śārṅgakam |
> satkṛtya śivayorājñāṃ maṃgalaṃ pradiśaṃtu me || 136 ||

134-136. **The four Mūrtis of Viṣṇu, viz Vāsudeva, Aniruddha, Pradyumna, and Saṃkarṣaṇa,** the ten Avataras viz—the fish, tortoise, boar, man-lion, dwarf, Rāma trio, Kṛṣṇa and the horse-faced Kalki, his discus, Nārāyañāstra, Pāñcajanya and the bow Śārṅga—**may these grant my desire at the behest of the two (Śiva & Śakti).**